# How the value of the integer variable is stored in a memory by bytes/bits?

Tags: c, data-types, storage, memory-usage, gnu

In C program I'm doing below stuff

```
int x  = 4;
```

Let us assume integer has 2 bytes in this case.
So my question here is
the variable **x** will hold two bytes that mean 16 bits. So here how the value **4** will be stored in 16 bits ?

Till now my understanding is the value 4 will be converted to Hex so it results [0x0004] and this hex value is stored in the 16 bit boxes ?

I dont know whether my understanding is correct but I need how the value of the **x** is mapped to 16 bit boxes ? 
It would be good if anyone provide structural/graphical representation about storing values in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do Computers Work?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81624/how-do-computers-work)

Comment: I just wanna know how the values are occupying the allocated memory rather than brief answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a 16bit OS then there'll be 2 bytes next to each other in memory. One with 00000100 in and the other with 00000000. Whether it's stored as 00000000-00000100 or 00000100-00000000 depends on whether your OS is little-endian or big-endian. 
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: you've only got 8 bits (one byte) in 00000100

Comment: Yes I agree @timB33 but I need how it is storing the numbers in the 16 boxes.Exactly I need graphical representation

Answer (score 1):

The exact representation is unspecified in the C standard, (which is partly why `int` might be 16, 32 or 64 bits)

A typical representation is [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), because it allows the same hardware to do both signed and unsigned arithmetic.

Decimal 4 is binary 0000000000000100. There is no "conversion", all values are bit strings.